# The height of the div does not grow dynamically

Tags: html

I went through most of the posts on this but nothing helped.

I need to increase the `div` to **100% height** so that it fits the length of the window and applicable to *child divs* too.

```
#container{
    width: 75%; 
    background-color: silver; 
    background-position: center;
    min-height: 100px;
    overflow : hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#header{
    background-color:infotext;
}

h1{
    margin-bottom: 0; 
    color: white;
}

#list{
    width: 20%; 
    background-color:window; 
    float: left;
    height:100%;
}
#links{
    width: 55%;
}
```

Code:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <h1 align="center">Represent</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="list">
            <span><h4>Fruits</h4></span>
            <hr>
            <p>Apple</p><br>
            <p>Mango</p><br>
            <p>Orange</p>
        </div >
        <div id="links">
        <iframe src="http://www.google.co.in" frameborder="0">
        </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The issue is that the `container div` and the rest of the `divs` does not expand even if the `iframe` size is big and hence, `scrollbar` appears. Any solutions?

---

Another issue:

The div of the iframe does not take up the full width. I put 20% for #list and 55% for #links so that it fits within the parent div #container 75%. This does not happen!!

Comment: What u want u want to dynamically increase div width when contain add or fix on browser window?

Comment: No, there is an iframe inside a div and to the left is the list. I just want the width if the div (containing iframe) to fill up the entire space left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `height: 100%;` on the `<html>` and `<body>` elements as well as the child elements that you want to occupy the full height:

Add this CSS:

```
html, body, .full-height {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0; // <-- to avoid unnecessary scrollbars.
}
```

Then just add the `full-height` class to the elements you want to occupy the full height of their container.

You need to **provide a demo** of your issue or I can't help you with all of your problems.

**A few tips though:**

1. Don't use the `align` attribute. It's deprecated. Use CSS floats instead.
2. Don't use the `infotext` or `window` CSS color values. Those are [system colors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/color_value#System_Colors). All system colors are deprecated as they only work in certain OS / browser combinations. Use one of the [valid color keywords](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/color_value#Color_keywords), or use hexadecimal / rgb notation.
3. Don't use `<br>` tags for visual spacing. Use CSS margin instead.
4. Don't stick block-level elements like `<h4>`s inside inline elements like `<span>`s.
5. There are very few cases where using an `iframe` is a good idea. Try rethinking your problem to see if you can come up with an alternative solution.
6. Make your `#header` element an actual `<header>` element. To support IE8- add the JS snippet at the bottom of this answer to your JS.
7. Make your `#list` element an actual [list element (`<ul>`)](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp). If you don't like the default styles of a list then reset them using the CSS snippet at the bottom of this answer.

**JS snippet:**

```
document.createElement('header');
```

**CSS snippet:**

```
ul.reset,
ol.reset {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: He wont get unnecessary scroll bars if he is using correct positioning, ofcourse, using margins in parent containers will get him in trouble

Comment: @Mr.Alien Setting the `<body>` element's height to 100% will cause scrollbars if you don't set its margin to 0, because most browsers give the `<body>` element a default 8px padding.

Comment: Thanks for the tips!! Actually, I did not put margin : 0 for the body as putting the height as 100% in all the divs helped. Though, margin : 0 does avoids the scrollbars of the page. Also, I put, overflow:hidden for one div as it was exceeding beyond the parent div and I had to put height:100% for the iframe too to avoid scrollbars for the iframe

Comment: @Web_Designer That's why we use resets `* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}` :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien That works too, just be careful to add the necessary margin back to headings and the like.

Comment: I've another issue...which I've described it above!!